# Retrieve "Applicable When" and "Success Criteria" from Dynamics CRM SLA programmatically

Tags: c#, .net, dynamics-crm, dynamics-365

Currently developing a console application to check all the SLAs in the Dynamics 365 instance.

How to retrieve the "applicable when" and "success criteria" from Dynamics CRM SLA programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That information is stored in the `applicablewhenxml` and `successconditionsxml` fields of the **slaitem** entity. You can use the following FetchXML to retrieve them:

```
<fetch>
  <entity name="slaitem" >
    <attribute name="applicablewhenxml" />
    <attribute name="successconditionsxml" />
  </entity>
</fetch>
```

As you can imagine from the names, the information is stored as XML. For example, for a success condition of Status equals to `Active`:

```
<and>
   <condition>
      <column id="colEntity" value="incident" />
      <column id="colAttribute" value="statecode" />
      <column id="colOperator" value="eq" />
      <column id="colStaticValue" value="0" dataslugs="" />
   </condition>
</and>
```